# Where should I ask questions specifically about privacy and anonymity?

Tags: discussion

Where should I ask questions specifically about privacy and anonymity, since IT Security is supposed to be about, well, security?

Are any of the other Stack Exchange forums more appropriate for it? If not, can anyone point out the "Stack Overflows" of privacy and anonymity out there?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate or merely a question that happens to have the same answer: [Has the IT Security S.E. evolved into a S.E. for information security?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/741) Privacy is on-topic here, since the protection of privacy is a security concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IT Security is the most appropriate place for this. Privacy is very closely connected to security so this is a natural place to ask these questions.

Comment: And anonymity? And privacy questions that are not directly IT?

Comment: IT anonymity and privacy would be appropriate. Non-IT is less applicable.

Answer (score 6):

We cover all areas of security that your normal security professional may encounter, which could include:

- Business continuity
- IT Disaster recovery
- Social Engineering
- Security Architecture
- Policies
- Regulatory Compliance
- IT Audit
- Forensics
- Anonymity
- Privacy

and many others

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in **personal** security, privacy, and anonymity you could try [superuser](http://superuser.com). It's for personal computing and they cover hardware and software. They have tags for security and privacy. The anonymity tag was rolled into the privacy tag.

The security tag description says:

> Questions on Super User tagged security are generally expected to
>   relate to specific software or hardware problems associated with
>   security considerations.
>
> Questions about protecting information assets from threats through
>   controls, security architecture and security management systems are
>   generally better suited for Security.StackExchange.

The privacy tag description says:

> Questions about protecting your privacy on your computer. Questions
>   about privacy in web applications belong in WebApps.

---

The [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) site covers anything to do with the personal use of sites like Facebook, Google, etc. Here's the "What kind of questions statement":

> Web Applications - Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of
>   web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>       Bookmarklets
>       Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

---

There's also a proposal for a new site called "Privacy" in Area 51:
[Privacy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38311/privacy)

Here's the description:

> Proposed Q&A site for privacy professionals and individuals to discuss
>   best practices as well as legal, cultural and regulatory requirements
>   for organizations that collect, use and store personal information.