# Would a question on how Facebook decided to suggest a friend on topic?

Tags: discussion, privacy

[This question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/810/where-should-i-ask-questions-specifically-about-privacy-and-anonymity) says that topics on privacy and anonymity are on topic. However my question would specifically be presenting facts on the how I met an individual and then how Facebook on the next day decided to show him as a friend suggestion.

The reason why I need to ask the question is because I am very interested as to how Facebook would know this suggestion because there is seemingly no connection UNLESS there is a privacy violation by another app other than Facebook.

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have anything to do with security or privacy.

One may not like the way Facebook works, but when you sign up to Facebook on your phone you give them permission to read all your contacts.

You may not like that level of privacy invasion, but you did agree to it - not on topic here.

Comment: The reason for asking the question was because the native Facebook app wasn't installed. I always use it through the browser. Anyway, turns out it was WhatsApp that shared the data with Facebook